# Change selectbox selection on img click

Tags: javascript, select

When someone clicks a specific link on my website I want the select box option to change to the option to a certain option by the value it has set.

I imagine I would do this by adding some sort of onClick that points to the value on each selection... but can't figure out the code to use.

Comment: Past some code and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

In regular JavaScript you could do something similar to:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var image = document.getElementbyId('someImage');

image.addEventListener('click', function() {
  selectBox.selectedIndex = 1; // specify the selected index here.
});
```

where you get a reference to the select box and image and add an event handler to the image to set the selected index of the select box.

If you have jQuery available, you can do similar:

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $('select').val('new value'); // specify the new value
});
```

Comment: I do have jQuery available, its actually going to be an image or link that can be clicked...  heres my code:<form action="action.php" method="post" class="addForm">
    <select name="productOptions[{$option.option_id}]" id="option_{$option.option_id}" class="textBox {if $option.required}required{/if}">
        <option value="13">Option</option>
    </select>
</form>

<a href="#"><img src="{$product.image}" alt="{$product.name}" class="thumb" /></a>
<a href="#">Monster</a>